# Display dropdown items using ThymeLeaf by reading values from the database.

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring Boot application and am trying to populate options in HTML with the contents of the database. For that I am using iterators in ThymeLeaf to display all those options. The snippet for that is:

```
<div class="col-1.5">
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="agentName">

                            <option value="">Select an agent</option>
                            <option th:each="log:${logs}"
                                    th:value="${log.agentName}"
                                    th:text="${log.agentName}"
                            >
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

I have this in my DAO class

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface AgentsDao extends CrudRepository<Agents,String>{       
    public List<Agents> findAll();
    public Agents findByagentId();    
}
```

I have this in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/log")
    public String log(Model model) {
        List<Agents> logs = agentsCRUD.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("logs", logs);
        return "log";
    }
```

Basically I have "agentId" as primary key in my Agents model(table). And there are thousands of agents and their name is represented by column: "agentName" All "agentName"s are what I am trying to display in HTML options using ThymeLeaf. Right now the code is has bugs. I am very new to Spring Framework(have only used it for a week) so I am having a very hard time figuring out how to do it.

Comment: What exceptions/errors are you getting and can you show the whole of your Controller please?

Comment: 1. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter available for part agentId SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals].  2. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract com.bulk.model.Agents com.bulk.dao.impl.AgentsDao.findByagentId()! No parameter available for part agentId SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is, Equals]. 3. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentsDao': Failed to create query method public abstract com.bulk.model.Agents com.bulk.dao.impl.AgentsDao.findByagentId()!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have 'agentName' in your 'Agents' class.
Also, are you trying to get whole Entity while fetching the Agents List from DB.
I mean if you just want to fetch the 'agentName', use 'ResultTransformer' in your query to get 'agentName' (in case if you're using Hibernate Framework).

Comment: Can you please show a quick example on how to use ResultTransformer ? Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For return list for dropdown most safe way is use

> modelattribute

```
   @ModelAttribute("logs")
    public List<Agents> log() {
        List<Agents> logs = agentsCRUD.findAll();
        return logs;
    }
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

In your  `public Agents findByagentId();` method you need to add the param for the agent id. eg:  `public Agents findByagentId(Long id);` Spring is expecting a param so is failing on start up and/or Bean creation from what I can tell.